# Entitlements are not valid sencha touch 2 native packaging

Tags: ios, ios4, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch and developed a small test app using sencha touch 2 and generated a

native package for i-os and it's working fine with the emulator but when i tried installing it

on the device it's falling in installation with the message entitlements are not valid. I have

generated the certificate from apple official site and also have the provisioning profile

for the same then why the installation fails?

Is there any way to specify the i-os version in packaging for which i have to develope the app

The same test app i have package for android device it's working fine.

Please help me any one.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 codesign -f -dvvv -s "iPhone Developer" /path/to/YourApp.app
```

where 'iPhone Developer' is a substring of the certificate in your keychain to use. Then try to load the .app file to your iPhone.

Also, make sure you don't have an expired certificate in your "My Certificates" section in your keychain. I had one and it was causing my builds to fail.

Let me know if this helps or not.